# Writing to CSV File in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am creating a clock for clocking into a business. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String Code;
    String Name;
    String InOut;
    Boolean Luke = true;
    String csvPath = "C:/users/luke/documents/C#/csvProject.csv";
    StringBuilder Header = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        TopMost = true;

        Header.AppendLine("Timestamp, Name");
        File.AppendAllText(csvPath, Header.ToString());
        textBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold);


    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Code = Code + button.Text;
        textBox1.Text = Code;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            TopMost = false;
        }
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear
        Code = null;
        textBox1.Text = Code;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //in or out
        DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        if (Code == "123")
        {
            Name = "Luke";
        }
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        csvData.AppendLine(timeStamp + "," + Name + "," + button.Text);
        File.AppendAllText(csvPath, csvData.ToString());
        Code = null;
        textBox1.Text = Code;
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

My layout consists of a number pad, in button, and out button. When the user presses the in button after they enter their code, the program should write in the CSV file: Timestamp, Name, In. When I tested the code by clocking in, the program writes one row correctly. When I clock in and then clock out, it creates two rows of me clocking in and one row of me clocking out. I was wondering if anyone could help me find what is going wrong in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty csvData after writing it to the file.

Comment: When I added    csvData = null;  at the end of button10_Click, the program crashes when I clock out. It works fine when I clock in.

Comment: What error you've encountered? Better to clear it rather than setting the value as null.

Comment: csvData.Clear(); instead of setting it to null.

Comment: What do you gain by having csvData as a stringBuilder instead of just  a local string. You seem to be writing to the file after setting it. And once you write it to file you don't need it anymore.